# Error de sintaxis haciendo un insert en php usando mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

El error que me sale es éste:

> Error: INSERT INTO lol(usuario, contraseña) VALUES('lol',
>   '$2y$10$L328iO1LneHP06ejOxWT4.grJ1pf1UQAmvbQ6ylp.UvEkdMuKFS/G') You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '�a)
>   VALUES('lol',
>   '$2y$10$L328iO1LneHP06ejOxWT4.grJ1pf1UQAmvbQ6ylp.UvEkdMuKFS/' at line
>   1

Y éste es el código PHP:

```
<?php 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "lol";
$password = "lol";
$dbname = "lol";


$con = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);


$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$clave =password_hash($_POST["contraseña"],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$sql = "INSERT INTO lol(usuario, contraseña)
VALUES('".$usuario."', '".$clave."')";


if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}

$con->close();

?>
```

Comment: Deberías mostrar como tienes armada la consulta, o sea, el contenido que guardas en la variable $sql. Seguro que allí tienes el error en tu insert.

Comment: Esta puesto , mira el codigo entero

Comment: tu campo se llama contraseña en la BD?

Comment: Tienes un problema con el juego de caracteres. La `ñ` es un carácter perfectamente válido como nombre de campo, pero debes usar el mismo juego de caracteres en el lado del cliente y del servidor. ¿Tendrías tiempo para que te solucione el problema o prefieres dejar de usar la `ñ` en el nombre del campo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te está dando error el carácter 'ñ' del nombre de la columna, lo mejor sería que cambies el nombre de la columna por contrasena.

Comment: Efectivamente era la maldita 'ñ'

Comment: La `ñ` es un carácter válido como nombre de campo, pero puede dar problemas si no coinciden los juegos de caracteres usados en la base de datos, la conexión y el propio archivo PHP. Cambiar `contraseña` por `contrasena` sólo te postpondrá la aparición de otro error relacionado con el juego de caracteres más adelante.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que sufres es debido a que tu base de datos está creada con un juego de caracteres `latin1_swedish_ci` y tu PHP está en `utf8`.

Para que MySQL se encargue de la conversión entre juegos de caracteres debemos indicarle cuál vamos a usar haciendo uso de [`mysqli::set_charset()`](https://php.net/es/mysqli.set-charset) como muestro a continuación:

```
// Establecemos la conexión con el servidor
$con = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
// Le indicamos que deseamos usar el juego de caracteres utf8
$con->set_charset('utf8');
```

Con ese pequeño cambio tu aplicación volverá a funcionar y, además, guardará correctamente cualquier texto que introduzcas en la base de datos a partir de ese momento (cosa que no funcionaría correctamente si no lo haces).

Además, para evitar los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) relacionados con la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL), deberías usar (por ejemplo) la función [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](https://php.net/es/mysqli.real-escape-string):

```
$usuario = $con->escape_string($_POST["usuario"]);
$clave = $con->escape_string(password_hash($_POST["contraseña"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
$sql = "
   INSERT INTO lol (usuario, contraseña)
   VALUES('$usuario', '$clave')
";
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que escapar tu variable clave así:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO lol(usuario, password)VALUES('".$usuario."',".$con->real_escape_string($clave).");";
```

Comment: Lo del nombre de campo contraseña, también puede ser el problema.